# position text alongside icon using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

My features HTML is code generated, I would like to display the text along side the icons but the only way I have managed to do it, is by `position:absolute;` and this is NOT good as some products have a cart box directly above the features and some dont, therefore absolute position doesnt work.

Is there a way to relatively position the feature names along side the icons using either css or jquery?

I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/nHHkQ/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="FeatureIconsWrapper">
    <div class="FeatureIconImages">
      <a title="CapacityChildren" href=
      "popup.aspx?title=CapacityChildren&amp;topic=feature_CapacityChildren" rel="icons"
      class="iconClick"><img title="CapacityChildren" alt="CapacityChildren" src=
      "http://i50.tinypic.com/hwh0ud.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="FeatureIconImages">
      <a title="EasyBackpackingSystem" href=
      "popup.aspx?title=EasyBackpackingSystem&amp;topic=feature_EasyBackpackingSystem"
      rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="EasyBackpackingSystem" alt=
      "EasyBackpackingSystem" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/hwh0ud.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="FeatureIconImages">
      <a title="EasyInflationSystem" href=
      "popup.aspx?title=EasyInflationSystem&amp;topic=feature_EasyInflationSystem" rel=
      "icons" class="iconClick"><img title="EasyInflationSystem" alt=
      "EasyInflationSystem" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/hwh0ud.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="FeatureIconImages">
      <a title="MaxLoadCapacity" href=
      "popup.aspx?title=MaxLoadCapacity&amp;topic=feature_MaxLoadCapacity" rel="icons"
      class="iconClick"><img title="MaxLoadCapacity" alt="MaxLoadCapacity" src=
      "http://i50.tinypic.com/hwh0ud.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="FeatureIconImages">
      <a title="Weight" href="popup.aspx?title=Weight&amp;topic=feature_Weight" rel=
      "icons" class="iconClick"><img title="Weight" alt="Weight" src=
      "http://i50.tinypic.com/hwh0ud.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <ul id="FeatureIconNamesWrapper">
      <li class="FeatureIconNames">ISO 6185-1</li>

      <li class="FeatureIconNames">ISO 6185-1</li>

      <li class="FeatureIconNames">ISO 6185-1</li>

      <li class="FeatureIconNames">ISO 6185-1</li>

      <li class="FeatureIconNames">ISO 6185-1</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="c1"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#FeatureIconsWrapper {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 236px;
}

div.FeatureIconImages, div#FeatureIconNames {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 17px !important;
}

div.FeatureIconImages {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

div.FeatureIconImages {
    width: 60px;
}


ul#FeatureIconNamesWrapper {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
}


li.FeatureIconNames {
    margin-bottom: 57px;
    margin-left: 85px !important;
}
```

[image: problem]

[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Try narrow it down to something specific. This is much too much code to wade through for a problem this simple.

Comment: I will produce a screeshot so you can see the problem. Or you could view the jsfiddle?

Comment: i just corrected it with minimum change in structure.just take the <img> out of <a>. check my post for detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$imgs = $('#FeatureIconsWrapper .FeatureIconImages'); // cache image wrappers for better performance
$('#FeatureIconNamesWrapper li').each(function(i,e){
    $imgs.filter(':eq(' + i + ')').after($(e).detach());
})​
```

[Proof of concept fiddle here – disregard the CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/nHHkQ/2/).

Note: This solution sucks for multiple reasons. If there is any way you can alter the markup: Do it!

Comment: `<li>` without `<ul>` wrapper, for starters. You sure could work around it …

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is your wrong structure of html.
If you can tweak your html as in my fiddle then you can easily obtain img - label pair using css float.
Please check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/cgj5U/

OR

You can even do this without changing your html structure. used `float:left` on both the main sections
http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/9dUDX/

Comment: Thanks but the code generated HTML cannot be changed. Any workarounds that i could do?

Answer (score 1):

i have edited the Fiddle.
take a look at here : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFCDeveloper/nHHkQ/14/)

Comment: Your solution is broken in Chrome.